# how can parse this xml file?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

How can I parse a file with this structure in android?

please help

> I tried a lot, but I could not parse this file on Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book>
<season id="1" name="one">
    <page id="1-1" text="Page content 1" />
    <page id="1-2" text="Page content 2" />
    <page id="1-3" text="Page content 3" />
</season>
<season id="2" name="two">
    <page id="2-1" text="Page content 1" />
    <page id="2-2" text="Page content 2" />
    <page id="2-3" text="Page content 3" />
    <page id="2-4" text="Page content 4" />
    <page id="2-5" text="Page content 5" />
    <page id="2-6" text="Page content 6" />
</season>
<season id="3" name="three">
    <page id="3-1" text="Page content 1" />
    <page id="3-2" text="Page content 2" />
    <page id="3-3" text="Page content 3" />
    <page id="3-4" text="Page content 4" />
    <page id="3-5" text="Page content 5" />
    <page id="3-6" text="Page content 6" />
</season>
</book>
```

this is my code:
  my class name is XmlReader
  i use this class in onCreate() method

```
public class XmlReader
{
List<Season> Seasons;
private Season season;
private String text;

public XmlReader()
{
    Seasons = new ArrayList<Season>();
}

public List<Season> getSeasons() {
    return Seasons;
}

public List<Season> parse(InputStream is){
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("season"))
                    {
                        season = new Season();

                        season.setSeason_id( (Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(0)) ) );

                        season.setSeason_name( parser.getAttributeValue(1) );
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("season"))
                    {
                        seasons.add(season);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("page"))
                    {

                        season.setPage_id(Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(0)));
                        season.setPage_text( parser.getAttributeValue(1) );
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType=parser.next();
        }
    }
    catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return season;
}
}
```

Comment: what have u used for parsing?

Comment: Show your code what you have tried

Comment: @mohammadkiani post your code,

Comment: `I tried a lot` show how exactly, and we'll help to fix it. You shouldn't ask for a full code, we can only help to fix your code.

Comment: please add your code to the question. Not the link to your code. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @VladMatvienko : added

Comment: ok, now what is the problem? What is not working in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try This**

```
   try {
                InputStream mInputStream = getAssets().open("XmlData.xml");

                 XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                 XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                myparser.setInput(mInputStream, null);


                int event = myparser.getEventType();
                while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)  {
                    String name=myparser.getName();
                    switch (event){
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            if(name.equals("page")){

                                Log.e("TAG",""+  myparser.getAttributeValue(null,"id"));
                                Log.e("Page content ",""+  myparser.getAttributeValue(null,"text"));

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    event = myparser.next();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thank. This code worked for me

Comment: welcome @mohammadkiani

Answer (score 0):

Probably what have you been looking for is DOM parser.DOMParser can parse XML or HTML source into a DOM Document.